# getservletcontext in JSP fragment

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm trying to diplay list of data (categories) with jstl tag in a jsp  fragment page (.jspf) but the servlet redirect the parameters to the ressource index.jsp with getRequestDispatcher.
Acctually, I cannot access to "categories" from the jsp fragment even if i declared the JSTL core library in the .jspf file using :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Code of servlet :

```
categorieDAO = new CategorieDAO(new HibernateUtil());
    getServletContext().setAttribute("categories", categorieDAO.findAll());
    try {
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println( "Erreur");
    }
```

Code in menu.jspf :

```
<c:forEach items="${categories}" var="categories">
        <li class="even"><a href="services.html">${categories.nomcategorie}</a></li>   
</c:forEach>
```

Code in index.jsp

```
<!-- start of left menu -->
<jsp:include page="WEB-INF/jspf/menu.jspf"></jsp:include>
<!-- end of left menu -->
```

Any idea to resolve my problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  resolve my problem by changing the extension .jspf to .jsp !